# Adress checkbox of class switch but only with the id light2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my problem is the following:

I styled my Checkboxes on my WebSite with [this IMG / CSS / jQuery Code](http://www.maissan.net/articles/jquery-switch/2)

The interesting part is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Iterate over checkboxes
      $("input[type=checkbox].switch").each(function() {
        // Insert mark-up for switch
        $(this).before(
          '<span class="switch">' +
          '<span class="mask" /><span class="background" />' +
          '</span>'
        );
        // Hide checkbox
        $(this).hide();
        // Set inital state
        if (!$(this)[0].checked) {
          $(this).prev().find(".background").css({left: "-56px"});
        }
      }); // End each()

      // Toggle switch when clicked
      $("span.switch").click(function() {
        // If on, slide switch off
        if ($(this).next()[0].checked) {
          $(this).find(".background").animate({left: "-56px"}, 200);

        // Otherwise, slide switch on
        } else {
          $(this).find(".background").animate({left: "0px"}, 200);
        }
        // Toggle state of checkbox
        $(this).next()[0].checked = !$(this).next()[0].checked;
      });
    }); // End ready()

</script>
```

Now I want to access:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="light2" class="switch">
```

How do I have to adress the ID Tag with JavaScript?

I tried something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span.switch + #light2").click(function(){
            if($(this).next()[0].checked)
            {
                alert('checked');
            }
            else
            {
                 alert('unchecked');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any hint

Comment: IDs **must be unique** in your code, so a simple `$('#light2')` should be enough.

Comment: Are you trying to do something different for `#light2`, or execute the same code as for other checkboxes with something additional for this one? If something completely different, in your first snippet use `$("input[type=checkbox].switch").not("#light2")` and `$("span.switch").not("#light2")`. If something additional, use `$("#light2")`, as suggested by @Ragnarokkr, in the last snippet.

Comment: yes it is unique but unfortunately this doesn't work. i think i tracked it down to the iphone style plugin because if i try to call this function on a input type checkbox without the class switch it works properly. any ideas?

Comment: i want to style every object with the class "switch" and wanna call different action on #light1 and #light2 via ajax.

Comment: If you saw my last comment, ignore it - I just saw the link at the top of your question.

Comment: for better explanation: [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img221/6666/bildschirmfoto20130204u.png) depending on the switch i want to execute different php scripts via ajax

Comment: I think I have it - in your last snippet you're detecting click on the actual checkbox, but in your first snippet it is the spans themselves. What you want is `$("#light2").prev("span.switch").click(function() {});`, I believe.

Comment: YEAH! Nice it works. GREAT!!!! I thank you 1000 times... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#light2").click(function(){
            if($("#light2").is(":checked"))
            {
                alert('checked');
            }
            else
            {
                 alert('unchecked');
            }
        });
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bA2fX/

Comment: Check out the fiddle which seems to work.  I'm not sure by maybe something else is at play here.

Comment: as i wrote in one comment above: [..] i think i tracked it down to the iphone style plugin because if i try to call this function on a input type checkbox without the class switch it works properly. do you have any idea how i could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to style **every** `.switch`ed element, you should do it via CSS.

If your needs are more complex then you can do it by selecting every `.switch` class element using `$('.switch')`. For example:

```
$('.switch').css('color', 'red');
```

Instead, to select specific elements with an ID (since it **must** be unique) you can simply to use `$('#light2')`. For example:

```
$('#light1').on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        /* your AJAX code */
    }
});

$('#light2').on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        /* your AJAX code */
    }
});
```

However, since part of your code is created at runtime by jQuery, you'll have to style and attach events (well, for this last you could also [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) at the end of the `onDomReady` pseudo-event, otherwise your code won't find the requested elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ClarkeyBoy, the solution is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#light2").prev("span.switch").click(function() {
            if($("#light2").attr("checked"))
            {
                alert('checked');
            }
            else
            {
                 alert('unchecked');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```